# как читать файл с определенной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня есть скрипт с условием которое выводит текст из файла до определенной строки:

```
fileProfession = open('profession.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')

print("""Приветствую, пользователь. Вот список профессий: 
1. Веб-дизайнер
2. Графический дизайнер
3. UI дизайнер
4. Front-end разработчик
5. Back-end разработчик
6. 3D-дизайнер
7. Программист""")

selectedProfession = int(input("Выбери одну: "))

web = 0

if (selectedProfession == 1):
    with fileProfession as in_file:
        for row in (line.rstrip() for line in in_file.readlines()):
            web += 1
            print(row)
            if(web==14):
                break
```

нужно добавить такое же условие но которое будет читать файл уже с 15 строки. Пробовал через `fileProfession.readlines()[15:]` но он выводит файл массивом что мне не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете получающийся список вывести как отдельные строки:

```
print('\n'.join(fileProfession.readlines()[15:]))
```